# expected identifier before '(' token on Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am writing an Arduino Programm on Arduino IDE and I have a problem, it says it is called stray 313 error: expected ')' before 'if'. How can I correct  it? I am very new at programming and I don´t know how to fix it. The problem is on the last "if line"
Here is the sketch

```
int LED1 = 3;
int LED2 = 5;
int LED3 = 6;
int sensor = 0;
int valor;
void setup() {
  pinMode (LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LED3, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  valor = analogRead (sensor);
  if ((valor ˃ 0) && (valor ˂ 170)) {
    analogWrite (LED1, 127);
    analogWrite (LED2, 0);
    analogWrite (LED3, 0);
  }
  if ((valor ˃= 170) && (valor ˂ 340)) {
    analogWrite (LED1, 255);
    analogWrite  (LED2, 0);
    analogWrite (LED3, 0);
  }
  if ((valor ˃= 340) && (valor ˂ 510)) {
    analogWrite (LED1, 255);
    analogWrite (LED2, 127);
    analogWrite (LED3, 0);
  }
  if ((valor ˃= 510) && (valor ˂ 680)) {
    analogWrite (LED1, 255);
    analogWrite (LED2, 255);
    analogWrite (LED3, 0);
  }
  if ((valor ˃= 680) && (valor ˂ 850)) {
    analogWrite (LED1, 255);
    analogWrite (LED2, 255);
    analogWrite (LED3, 127);
  }
  if ((valor ˃= 850) && (valor ˂ 1023)) {
    analogWrite (LED1, 255);
    analogWrite (LED2, 255);
    analogWrite (LED3, 255)
  }
  else {
    analogWrite (LED1, 0);
    analogWrite (LED2, 0);
    analogWrite (LED3, 0);
  }
  delay (15);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using some weird characters for `<` and `>`. Maybe there are some others like non breakable space, but it usually get fixed by posting on web or so.

Another error is not having semicolon after one of the analogWrite();